# How can I tell if my user upgraded to a new phone, or restored from a backup in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, itunes, uuid

I want to make getting a new device as easy as possible in my iOS app.

However, I want to ensure that the old instance of the app (and more importantly the data) is no longer accessible on the old phone.

How can I track the uniqueness of a phone, and if the app has been installed on more than one device?

My goal isn't to control licensing, but rather to make sure the user knows what is "out there".

(My app stores private keys in the app container, and I want to ensure these keys don't fall into the wrong hands... hence the reason for my question)

Answer (score 0):

`UIDevice` offers [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor)

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.